# How to find specific event ID in archivedlog

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-5.1

Hope you all are doing fine.
I have a question, i want to find a specific event id in a log that is archived but there are so many of them that i want go through each one of them

I have found a site on how you can do that http://blog.microsoftme.com/2014/05/09/powershell-parsing-of-archived-event-logs/  but the output i get is "Parsing C:\logs.evtx"

This is the code :

```
`Get-ChildItem -include *Sec*.evtx -Path x:\loggingarchive\ -recurse |

ForEach-Object {“Parsing $($_.fullname)`r`n”



Try {

$TotalSearch+=Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{

Path=$_.fullname
Id=4738;
StartTime= 10/11/2020
EndTime= 4/10/2022
} -EA Stop

$TotalSearch+=Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{

Path=$_.fullname
Id=5139;
StartTime= 10/11/2020

EndTime=4/10/2021
} -EA Stop

} Catch [System.Exception] {“Done”}} > C:\Users\user\Documents\logs.txt`
```

What am i doing wrong here,
Instead of getting the events i get the output as noted above

Comment: You need to quote those timestamps

Comment: You also don't output `$TotalSearch`

Comment: and you can query multiple log ids in one go, `Id` can take an array (`int32[]`)